# Adding a span on Rails 3 - Where I have to add the span?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, css

I am pretty new on Rails and Ruby and I cannot find the answer to add a span inside this link_to

```
<p class="withButtons" >
   <%= link_to 'Répondre', lawyer_answers_path(@current_lawyer ? 'mon-compte' : ''), :class => 'button answerRevealer reply' %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a block to link_to

```
<%= link_to lawyer_answers_path(@current_lawyer ? 'mon-compte' : ''), :class => 'button answerRevealer reply' do %>
  <span>Répondre</span>
<% end %>
```